# iPhone won't connect to internet

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, internet

My iPhone SE connects to my WiFi/router/modem (WRM) fine, but it says "No Internet Connection".  I've never had this problem with my iPhone before.

Two other laptops connected to the same WRM access the internet just fine.  Logging on to the modem, I see all three devices connected to the WRM.

I followed an [Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204051) page and [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/article/210480/iphone_annoyances.html) page, cycling the power on the phone, then resetting the network connections.  After logging back on to the WRM, I get the same lack of internet access.

If I use the phone instead of the laptops to log into the WRM using its numerical http address, it times out.  I don't even get to the page for entering user name and password.

Here are one laptop's data from `ipconfig /all`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-B6-FC-01-C6
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Here is the other laptop:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-D9-87-13-CE-5A
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.103(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 2019-01-27 19:53:16
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 2019-01-31 00:14:54
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                    0.0.0.0
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

The data from the iPhone is

```
Configure IP: Automatic
IP Address: 169.254.184.137
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Router: << blank >>
```

I can't help but notice that the Subnet Mask is different, and the IP Address is very different,

What else can I try?

My WRM is the TP-Link TD-W9970.  My iOS version is 12.1.2.  I don't recall approving an update recently.  There is apparently a version 12.1.3 available, but without connectivity, I can't install it.

Comment: It'd be possible to install the iOS update via iTunes, since one or more of your computers seem to have a working internet connection.

Comment: Thanks, JW8.  I will try that if I ever run into this problem again.  I never run iTunes, so it will be a journey of discovery....

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, DHCP is not enabled on your laptop, but it has the right configuration, so I figure either DHCP must have been disabled on your router recently, or your phone was configured with static addresses which got cleared recently.

For a quick fix, try filling in the Router, IP address, and subnet mask fields on your phone after choosing Manual for "Configure IP". Something like:

```
Configure IP: Manual  
IP address: 192.168.1.123  
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0  
Router: 192.168.1.1
```

But you probably want to fix the settings on your router so you don't have to configure every device that connects to your network in the future.

Look for a setting that enables DHCP in your router's administrative interface, possibly on http://192.168.1.1

Comment: OK, thanks. I have to figure out what I did in the past. I recall following instructions somewhere to make the laptop's IP address fixed. This was needed by an app, [AkrutoSync](http://www.akruto.com/ip-address-changes/#ip_update_instructions_for_ios), which syncs Calendar & Contacts between the Phone and Outlook on the laptop. I don't recall changing the router, so I will probably (re)discover that I made the change on the laptop. If so, then it seems to me that it would not be a router problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that the fixed IP was due to a setting on that particular laptop.  The other laptop doesn't have this setting (I added the `ipconfig /all` output to the question. I'm afraid that this means the problem is with the phone, and tomorrow, I will check whether your manual configurations enable internet access.

Comment: It is, I just assumed that the DHCP service was disabled because your (working) laptop was set up with a fixed address, and your phone was not able to get one through DHCP. This could be the case, the 4 day lease on the laptop configured to use DHCP is set to expire in the (near) future... so it could stop working as soon as it fails to renew the lease. Either way, as long as you haven't set up to deny your phone access to the internet specifically, manually assigning an address should work, or at least rule out a few things.

Comment: I have no idea why, but it works today. I did nothing. IP address 192.168.1.100, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, Router 192.168.1.1.  Thanks for offering some suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the router allowed the iPhone to connect via DHCP.  I can't guarantee that it works for all cases of this problem, but it's another quiver for your bow.